# Java Selenium webdriver filling list webelement manually

Tags: java, list, selenium, webdriver

first of all:
I want to fill a List manually with `element.add();`

Because the elements of the page I am working with is just showing a specific range of elements, I can't just load all elements in a `List<WebElement>`.

That's why I want to do functions to `check if an element exists` in my List, if it doesn't exists there I will add it.

I want to know if there is a way to iterate specific elements like `element.next();`

Here is the xpath I am getting my elements:

`###.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[starts-with(@href, '/p/')]"));`

Comment: You can take your webelement inisde list and then iterate through it

Answer (score 0):

You ca use following snippet to fulfill your requirement

```
public boolean isDropdownOptionExists(String optionToBeVerified, By optionWhereToBeVerified) {
        boolean isOptionFound = false;
        Select optionsInDropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(optionWhereToBeVerified));
        List<WebElement> availableOptions = optionsInDropDown.getOptions();
        for(WebElement option: availableOptions) {
            if(option.getText().equals(optionToBeVerified)) {
                isOptionFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isOptionFound;
    }
```